# How to pass an input value from a modal-dialog in HTML and get it in java servlet using AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I'm trying to implement `search method` in my project and I want to pass the query from the `HTML` page to the `search servlet` , I tried so many ways but when I print the value passed to the `search servlet` I get `null`,I don't know what is wrong:Is it the way I pass the value from `HTML`? Or Is it the way I read the value in the `Servlet`?

Here's what I tried last:

`Page.html`:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input ng-model="searchinput" placeholder="search channels, users " ng-change="search()" />&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `Controller` that contains the modal:

```
$scope.search = function() {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/SearchServlet",$scope.searchinput)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.records = response;
            $scope.result = $scope.records;//this variable will hold the search results
        });
};
```

`SearchServlet.java`:

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
String query=reader.readLine();
System.out.println(query);
```

I tried also `getParameter("searchinput")` but nothing worked.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to read the documentation of $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, especially of the config object you're supposed to pass as second argument of $http.get (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage), and especially how to pass GET params using this object. Everything becomes much simpler when you read documentation.

Comment: @MicD thanks it worked!

Comment: @JB Nizet thank you!